# Can not find the price of products in ubercart tables

Tags: 6, ubercart

I need to export products from Ubercart, the problem I am facing is the price of products is shown 0.000 in uc_products in all related fields (list_price, cost, sell_price) for almost every product but on admin side and front end every product has price more than 0.000.

my question is **Where else the price could be store in ubercart tables other than uc_products?**

Any where in cache tables, attribute wise or somewhere else?

Comment: There are loads of modules that affect Ubercart pricing. What add-on modules do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what modules are installed on the site. But prices were in different tables for different currencies, found them finally

```
content_field_price_usd
content_field_price_eur
```